# adress pointer cast to struct

Tags: c, database, pointers, struct

I got an issue with the usage of pointers with structs.

I have a databank and each entry is declared as struct (where the members represent the db-item).

Now I want to print each parsed entry into a file and have to use pointers to point to a specific entry in the database. The following code snippet curses the problem:

```
/* print database entries */
    i = 0;
    while (i < *(uint32_t *)(*ptr_to_s_20b_parse_entries + 0xc)) {
      ptr_s_db_entry = *(s_db_entry **)(ptr_to_s_20b_parse_entries[2] + i * 4);
      if (ptr_s_db_entry->show == 0) {
        printf("[%3d] [%s] [%s]\n",i,ptr_s_db_entry->ptr_e_title,ptr_s_db_entry->ptr_e_text);
      }
      i = i + 1;
    }
  }
  return;
```

The Error:

> [Error] 's_db_entry' undeclared (first use in this function)

The following variables are declared:

```
  struct s_db_entry *ptr_s_db_entry;

struct s_db_entry {
    byte show; // 0 = show, 1 = don't show
    byte strlen_e_title;
    short strlen_e_text;
    int *ptr_e_title;
    int *ptr_e_text;
};
```

The ptr_to_s_20b_parse_entries is a parameter in from the caller.

Thank you already!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need

```
(struct s_db_entry **)
```

instead of

```
(s_db_entry **)
```

since it's not `typedef`'d.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you did not show that part, `s_db_entry` is not a *type* in your code.

In the code

```
 ptr_s_db_entry = *(s_db_entry **)(ptr_to_s_20b_parse_entries[2] + i * 4);
```

need to be changed to

```
ptr_s_db_entry = *(struct s_db_entry **)(ptr_to_s_20b_parse_entries[2] + i * 4);
                   ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

*[Error] 's_db_entry' undeclared (first use in this function)*

There a a couple of suggestions for this.
Changing the definition to create a `typedef` of the struct will address the problem.   Change this:

```
struct s_db_entry {
    byte show; // 0 = show, 1 = don't show
    byte strlen_e_title;
    short strlen_e_text;
    int *ptr_e_title;
    int *ptr_e_text;
};
```

To this: (also suggesting a name change here.)

```
//typedef struct s_db_entry {//name tag may be unnecessary at this point 
typedef struct {
    byte show; // 0 = show, 1 = don't show
    byte strlen_e_title;
    short strlen_e_text;
    int *ptr_e_title;
    int *ptr_e_text;
}db_entry_s;//note, typedef symbol is unique from name tag if both are to be used.
```

This would of course require that

```
(struct s_db_entry **)
```

Become this:

```
(db_entry_s **)
```

(Note that it is more common to see a suffix `_s` to indicate a struct  `typedef` than eg. prepending `s_`.)

Also in your code you show this declaration `struct s_db_entry  ptr_s_db_entry;` prior to defining the actual struct being referenced.  It should be place beneath the `struct` (or `struct typedef`, should you choose to use that method.) definition.

```
typedef struct {
    byte show; // 0 = show, 1 = don't show
    byte strlen_e_title;
    short strlen_e_text;
    int *ptr_e_title;
    int *ptr_e_text;
}db_entry_s;

db_entry_s *ptr_db_entry_s;
```